# jQuery add attribute on a element set to display none

Tags: jquery

I need to add the following attribute on a hidden element:

```
$("#payWithNewCard select").attr('data-abide-validator', 'checkexpiry');
```

The problem is that my select is set to display none as I am using a plugin to customize it.

The following is not working currently.

```
    $('#paymentMethodNewCard').on('click', function(){
        $("#payWithNewCard select").attr('data-abide-validator', 'checkexpiry');
    });

HTML:

            <div class="small-4 columns expiryDateWrapper">
                <label>{{ 'EXPIRYDATE'|trans }} *</label>
                <select class="sel-box month" name="ccExpirationMonth" data-abide-validator="checkExpiry">
                    <option value="">MM</option>
                    {% for month in 1..12 %}
                        <option value="{{ "%02d"|format(month) }}">{{ "%02d"|format(month) }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <select class="sel-box year" name="ccExpirationYear" data-abide-validator="checkExpiry">
                    <option value="">YYYY</option>
                    {% set thisYear = date()|date("Y") %}
                    {% for year in thisYear..thisYear+Booking.CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRES_YEARS_AHEAD %}
                        <option value="{{ year }}">{{ year }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
```

The class "sel-box" triggers the plug in to hide the native select and recreate a custom select with span elements and that is why the select is hidden. However for FOundation abide to work I need to have the data attribute specified above on the actual select.

Comment: That code should work, although you should use `data('abide-validator', 'checkexpiry')`. Assuming that this data attribute is associated with a plugin, you probably need to set the property on the instance of that, not just adding it to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click write `change` event and use `$(this)` in change event function.

```
$('#paymentMethodNewCard').on('change', function(){
    $(this).attr('data-abide-validator', 'checkexpiry');
});
```

Comment: This is wrong as it won't work with the example given by the OP. You don't actually know which tag is `#paymentMethodNewCard` and the OP actually adds a data-attribute to a child `select` element (which appears to be hidden)...

Comment: In which dropdown it will come `month` or `year`?